# How to give key_prefix, variable values while caching in Flask-Cache

Tags: python, caching, python-2.7, flask, flask-cache

We can cache any view/non-view function as

```
@cache.cached(timeout=50, key_prefix='all_comments')
```

Can we give key_prefix some variable values. Let say, I'm caching a function as

```
@cache.cached(timeout=50, key_prefix=value)
def get_all_comments(value):
```

Can we give key_prefix as the same arguments as we are getting in function. If not argument, then atleast some other variable by any proper way.

Answer (score 1):

In [the docs](http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Cache/#flask.ext.cache.Cache.cached) it says

> New in version 0.3.4: Can optionally be a callable which takes no arguments but returns a string that will be used as the cache_key.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you are looking for is the `@cache.memoize` decorator that takes the function arguments as cache keys, giving you the opportunity to cache the function results for distinct values.

```
@cache.memoize(timeout=50)
def get_all_comments(value):
```

In this example, I'm caching for 50s.

Comment: Minor correction: The timeout is in seconds, not ms.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [make_cache_key](https://flask-caching.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#make-custom-cache-key) to provide a function for generating the key. The arguments of the cached function (i.e. get_all_comments) are passed as keyword arguments to the make_cache_key function.

```
def make_cache_key(**kwargs):
   return kwargs['value']

@cache.cached(timeout=50, make_cache_key=make_cache_key)
def get_all_comments(value):
   ....
```